# How do I add an animation "div" to a "img" in jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, html, dynamic

I am making a game in which the "player" `img` fights other "monster" `img`s, the fight is a whole bunch of rounds. Each time a hit happens, I display a "hit" as numbers that fade out upwards in a div (kind of hard to describe). To illustrate like so:

[image] 
[image] 
[image]
[image]

(hope that shows what I mean)

The way I did this was I added a `div` with each `img` when I made the `img` originally. With an `id` connected to the `object` connected to the player/monster (i.e. `monster0health` etc.).  Then I put this code in my file.

```
$("#" + displayHealthDivId).delay(250).animate({
    opacity: 100,
    top: "+=" + (3 * (scale / 10))
}, 0);
$("#" + displayHealthDivId).html(healthLost);
$("#" + displayHealthDivId).animate({
    opacity: 0,
    top: "-=" + (3 * (scale / 10))
}, 1000, function () {});
```

As the name suggests `healthLost` is the health that was lost - the text I want to display in said `div` and `scale` is the `img`s `height`.

### css

```
.healthLost{
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    left: 0;
    top: -10px;
    z-index:2;
    width:100%;

    opacity:0;

    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:red;

    pointer-events:none;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do this without creating a `div` when I make the `img`. **How can I in jQuery create a `div`, in a certain position relative to a `img`?** I then want to fade it out, (upwards) and keep it (at least) as long as the fight lasts.

too much code to make a fiddle so [link here](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/adventure.html).

Comment: Can you through together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: sorry was going to link to site, gonna edit.

Comment: It will be easier to help with a fiddle isolating the issue rather than a link to the full site

Comment: its just one page, but i got 100's of lines of code and to make a fiddle would take almost a hour. sorry if i was able to i would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/jn53x/)***

It was a little hard to mock your exact scenario. I used some placeholder images. Basically you are going to need to do a few things with css to make this work. And then with jQuery as well.

First, you should make sure that the container of each image is set as position:relative. This will allow for relative values to be used along with top to manipulate the absolutely positioned dynamic div.

Next, you can make the div like this

```
var hp = "-99";
var lost = $("<div class='healthLost'>");
lost.attr("data-tar",t);
lost.html(hp);
```

In order to hold the divs which showed the hp, you can always have an array available somewhere

```
var hits = [];
```

and then in your animation callback you can store the hit divs

```
lost.animate({
 opacity: 0,
 top: "-=" + (3 * (scale / 10))
}, 1000, function () {
    hits.push($(this).clone(false));
    $(this).remove();
    console.log(hits);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery you would have something like this

```
function strike(el, dmg) {
  var template = '<div class="damage" data-monster-id="el">' + dmg + '</div>';
  $(el).parent() // Parent is your .boardspot
       .append(template);
  $(el).siblings('.damage:last')
       .slideUp('slow'); // For fancier effect you will have to look at jquery ui
}

// To strike a monster with id monsters[12]
strike('#monsters[12]', 200);
```

The CSS for `.damage`:

```
z-index: 9999;
font-size: 20px;
color: red;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
top: 20%;
```

The above is crudely tested, so use it as a reference.